# Read and write Hashmap in Android

Tags: java, android

I have some data files that I use to initialize HashMaps in my Android program, and save the updated HashMaps during the program. These files are currently kept in the assets folder.

1. The only way to read and write a HashMap (that I am aware of) in regular java program is to use `ObjectOutpuStream` and `ObjectInpuStream`, however, it seems that currently these data files can only be accessed as `InputStream` object using `getAssets().open(filepath)`, and I have no idea how to convert `InputStream` object to read and write HashMaps, any suggestion on this?
2. Is there any alternative ways to achieve this? (other than storing the data files in internal or external storage)

Comment: The constrcutor to a `ObjectInputStream` is a `InputStream`  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: Currently when I try to initialize `ObjectInputStream` with the obtained `InputStream`, the returned `HashMap` is none. This is probably caused by the fact that these HashMaps were originally stored in a different way. So how can I rewrite these files in the assets folder?